How to Copy Conditional Formatting for Other Rows
In my excel sheet for one hundred rows or so I have data in various columns (L, R, X, AD, AM, AV, ...).
I would like to highlight the minimum value in every call per row in these columns.
Is there an easy method to copy this 'Highlight Bottom 1 value' rule in Excel?
Since all the columns aren't next to each other, I don't believe I can 'Copy Format'.
I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this besides selecting each cell per row 100 times.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Please [edit] your question and add more details. What data is in the other columns? How many columns do you want to compare? Show an example table. Mayve use e.g. https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/ to convert the table from your spreadsheet.

Solution with a helper column

Choose a helper column, e.g. AZ, for formulas.

In AZ1 insert a formula like =MIN(L1;R1;X1;AD1;AM1;AV1). You can add a cell by clicking on it.

Copy the formula from AZ1 to AZ2, AZ3 etc. down to the last row.

Select the range A1 to AV1 and define conditional formatting "Highlight cells rules" - "equal to", select cell AZ1 and modify it from $AZ$1 to $AZ1, resulting in a rule with condition Cell Value = $AZ1. This should highlight the lowest value in the first row, provided that no other column contains a matching value. Otherwise you might have to select all relevant cells in row 1 for the range of the conditinal formatting. (untested)

Select row 1 and copy.

Select row 1 to last and paste special - other paste options - format.

If required, you can hide the helper column or exclude it from the print area.


